# Is it valid to give a style element an ID?

Tags: validation, html

It says [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html) that it is not within HTML4, though I don't really see where that's spelled out in the text.
From what I can tell, based on [this](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute), it is ok to do so in HTML5 but I'm not entirely sure (assuming style is an HTML element?)

I am using this to rotate out a stylesheet and want it to be as valid as possible according to HTML5 specs, so wondering if I should rewrite it with a data-* element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 Interesting question!

Instead of using a `style` block, you should consider linking (`link`) to your stylesheets and then switch them out by referencing an `id` or a `class`.

---

That said, `title` is perfectly acceptable for a `style` tag in HTML5.  You can use this as a hook for your stylesheet switching.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-style-element

Fyi... this validates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style title="whatever"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test body
  </body>
</html>
```

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: you know what, I'm an idiot. I was using a link tag, and ids are valid for them even under 4.01, so.. moot point

Comment: Well at least we know now @Damon ;-) Thx

Answer (score 2):

I've just put the following code into the W3C validator and it has no errors :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style id="test"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test body
  </body>
</html>
```

I think the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a good resource for this type of thing, it is marked as experimental but that's because the standard is yet to be be finalised.

Comment: You validated against HTML5. The question is asking about HTML4.

Comment: Actually, OP said I *want it to be as valid as possible according to HTML5 specs*

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid in HTML4 (as per the spec) and data-* attributes are not either. That is, the document will not validate against the Doctype spec if you use these attributes.

Regardless of whether the document validates or not, browsers will ignore elements that they do not recognize.

Style tags are DOM elements like any other tag, so you can add any attributes you want.